# Error when running a python script - invalid syntax

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I keep getting this error when running a python script

```
sudo python net-creds.py
  File "net-creds.py", line 75
    ipr = Popen([‘/usr/local/bin/ip’, 'route'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=DN)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what are you doing with the output? If you want to store the output you can use check_output: `c = check_output(["ip","route"])`

Answer (score 2):

You are using " ` " instead of `'`.So try this

```
ipr = Popen(['/usr/local/bin/ip', 'route'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=DN)
```

Comment: To clarify: the invalid version has "smart quotes." The valid version has ordinary "dumb quotes."